# Migration of CSV into paragraphs fails with unexpected error

Tags: 8, migrations, importing-exporting, paragraphs

I try to import CSV files into a Drupal 8 installation but I can't manage to make the relationship to paragraphs appear. I followed the steps of [this tutorial](https://www.mtech-llc.com/blog/charlotte-leon/migration-csv-data-paragraphs) but can't figure out how to make it work. I created a simple test case to find the error:

I extended the regular *article* content type with a paragraphs field called *field_persons* for linking each article to a list of persons with roles. This paragraphs entity has to fields called *field_name* (for now only text) and *field_role* (taxonomy_term).

The yaml file for paragraphs migration looks like that and import processes without error:

```
id: article_persons
label: Import persons for articles

source:
  plugin: csv
  delimiter: '|'
  enclosure: '"'
  path: article_persons.csv
  header_row_count: 1
  keys:
    - id
  column_names:
    0:
      id: 'ID'
    1:
      name: 'Name'
    2:
      rol: 'Role'

process:
  field_nombre: name
  field_para_rol: 
    plugin: entity_generate
    source: role
    value_key: name
    bundle_key: vid
    bundle: rol
    entity_type: taxonomy_term
    ignore_case: true

destination:
  plugin: 'entity_reference_revisions:paragraph'
  default_bundle: article_persons
```

The yaml file for article migration looks like that and import processes without error:

```
id: article
label: Import articles

source:
  plugin: csv
  delimiter: '|'
  enclosure: '"'
  path: articles.csv
  header_row_count: 1
  keys:
    - id
  column_names:
    0:
      id: 'ID'
    1:
      title: 'Title'
    2:
      person: 'Persons'

process:
  title: title
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: article
  field_person/target_id: 
    -
      plugin: migration_lookup
      migration: article_persons
      no_stub: true
      source: id
    -
      plugin: extract
      index:
        - '0'
  field_person/target_revision_id: 
    -
      plugin: migration_lookup
      migration: article_persons
      no_stub: true
      source: id
    -
      plugin: extract
      index:
        - 1

destination:
  plugin: 'entity:node'
migration_dependencies:
  required: 
    - article_persons
  optional: { }
```

But when I try to access the node I get an "unexpected error" with a huge log message:

```
Error: Call to a member function getEnabledBehaviorPlugins() on null en Drupal\paragraphs\ParagraphViewBuilder->buildMultiple() (línea 37 de /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/paragraphs/src/ParagraphViewBuilder.php)
#0 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityViewBuilder.php(220): Drupal\paragraphs\ParagraphViewBuilder->buildMultiple(Array)
#1 [internal function]: Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder->build(Array)
#2 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(378): call_user_func(Array, Array)
#3 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(195): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, false)
#4 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Template/TwigExtension.php(490): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array)
#5 /var/www/html/sites/default/files/php/twig/5a008e9488529_field.html.twig_9MJB5waMfG4Lcal_NDL6EY6rM/NRByUw7bYmwhNIE9WTZfCRjJ3XUAFBB122RdQTC3JsI.php(128): Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension->escapeFilter(Object(Drupal\Core\Template\TwigEnvironment), Array, 'html', NULL, true)
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(432): __TwigTemplate_85d8aba47ed6496a0f2e8e6407c9fc1802c03e707a72d9d0c1465c62e125a308->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#7 /var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(403): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#8 /var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(411): Twig_Template->display(Array)
#9 /var/www/html/core/themes/engines/twig/twig.engine(64): Twig_Template->render(Array)
#10 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Theme/ThemeManager.php(384): twig_render_template('sites/all/theme...', Array)
#11 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(437): Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render('field', Array)
#12 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(450): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array)
#13 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(195): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, false)
#14 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Template/TwigExtension.php(490): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array)
#15 /var/www/html/sites/default/files/php/twig/5a008e9488529_node.html.twig_fOU7Z1faeO15YpZRrtd-F9Ksv/yHD4dpGBMlI8SMMqQ5z-QVQGNcCrpCuzsSt1E4ShcEU.php(111): Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension->escapeFilter(Object(Drupal\Core\Template\TwigEnvironment), Array, 'html', NULL, true)
#16 /var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(432): __TwigTemplate_38fa5b6b1f6bdfd56bb4dba5e7d13d0f61126e79c913612089235f94cf12db1f->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#17 /var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(403): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#18 /var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(411): Twig_Template->display(Array)
#19 /var/www/html/core/themes/engines/twig/twig.engine(64): Twig_Template->render(Array)
#20 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Theme/ThemeManager.php(384): twig_render_template('sites/all/theme...', Array)
#21 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(437): Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render('node', Array)
#22 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(195): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, false)
#23 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/MainContent/HtmlRenderer.php(226): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array, false)
#24 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(576): Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\{closure}()
#25 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/MainContent/HtmlRenderer.php(227): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object(Drupal\Core\Render\RenderContext), Object(Closure))
#26 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/MainContent/HtmlRenderer.php(117): Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->prepare(Array, Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), Object(Drupal\Core\Routing\CurrentRouteMatch))
#27 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/MainContentViewSubscriber.php(90): Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->renderResponse(Array, Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), Object(Drupal\Core\Routing\CurrentRouteMatch))
#28 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Component/EventDispatcher/ContainerAwareEventDispatcher.php(108): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\MainContentViewSubscriber->onViewRenderArray(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForControllerResultEvent), 'kernel.view', Object(Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))
#29 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(158): Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.view', Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForControllerResultEvent))
#30 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(68): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1)
#31 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/Session.php(57): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#32 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/KernelPreHandle.php(47): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#33 /var/www/html/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(99): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#34 /var/www/html/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(78): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#35 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/ReverseProxyMiddleware.php(47): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#36 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/NegotiationMiddleware.php(50): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#37 /var/www/html/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#38 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php(657): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#39 /var/www/html/index.php(19): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
#40 {main}.
```

This [bug report](https://www.drupal.org/node/2895561) seems to indicate that the paragraphs which is referenced doesn't exist. So it seems to have to do something with the ids, but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could make it working fixing two things in my code:

First. Adding the paragraph machine name as type to process statement:

```
process:
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: persona
```

Second. Changing the source parameter to the column which contains the id of the related paragraph.

After reading the Drupal issue list for Entity Reference Revisions I learned that now there is a more simple way to specify the *target_id* and *target_revision_id*. With the help from [this thread](https://www.drupal.org/node/2825565) I ended up using this process code for node import of *field_person*:

```
  field_person:
    -
      plugin: skip_on_empty
      method: process
      source: person
    -
      plugin: explode
      delimiter: ,
    -
      plugin: migration_lookup
      migration: article_persons
      no_stub: true
    -
      plugin: iterator
      process:
        target_id: '0'
        target_revision_id: '1'
```